# How can i Fix ping through iptables?

Tags: iptables, bash

I am making a script with iptables on the firewall machine and when executing it and I want to ping a web page I get an error: ping: [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com): Temprary failed to name resolution and this happens when I run the script, when I restart everything goes perfectly without any problem, I also tried resolv.conf and it doesn't work.

PS: There are two interfaces enp0s3 that goes to the internet and another one enp0s8 that is from an Internal LAN

I pass you the script

```
sudo iptables -F

sudo iptables -X

sudo iptables -Z

sudo iptables -t nat -F

sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP

sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.30.10:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.30.10:443
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.30.11:22

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.30.0/24 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s8 -p tcp --dport 22 -d 172.16.30.11 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -m state --state ESTABLISHED, RELATED -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s3 -i enp0s8 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s8 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p icmp -j ACCEPT


sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s8 -i enp0s3 -d 172.16.30.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s8 -i enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s8 -i enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 172.16.30.1 -p icmp -j DROP

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s3 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s3 -p icmp -j ACCEPT


sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s8 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s8 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: did you allow port 53 tcp/udp? or uding a local cache Nameserver?

Comment: what do you mean "you tried resolv.conf"? Do you mean that you manually added the IP address for Facebook in there? Can you ping the IP address for Facebook?

Comment: Besides missing a rule to allow 53 outgoing, you seem to be missing a commonly used rule or equivalent: `ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED`.  This allows traffic back in from sessions originating from your machine -- including DNS replies which currently would be dropped even if you did allow it out.

Comment: with iptables how can i include?

Comment: What do you want to include? To add a rule at the end, `iptables -A <chain>`. To insert a rule before position 10, `iptables -I <chain> 10`. See the manual page.